# Format String to specific datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert the string "2015/07/05" to the format 08-MAR-2015.
The code below keeps getting detected as an invalid datetime format (i.e the else statement below)

**C# Code**

```
string format = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
string dateString = "2015/07/05";
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dateTime));
}
else // Invalid datetime format
{
MessageBox.Show("UBD date is not a valid date format: " + dateTime.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us what `format` is... and when you use `Convert.ToString(dateTime)`, that's not showing what format you want, is it?

Answer (score 2):

String formatting is performed by the `String.Format` method, not `Convert.ToString`. The `Convert` methods try to convert one type to another using the current culture's default format where required.

Try the following

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"dd-MMM-yyyy",someDate);
```

This will ensure that the English month names will be used.

In non-English cultures the following line will return the local month name

```
String.Format("dd-MMM-yyyy",someDate);
```